# Invisible characters - ASCII

Tags: facebook, unicode, character, ascii

Are there any **invisible** characters? I have checked Google for invisible characters and ended up with many answers but I'm not sure about those. Can someone on Stack Overflow tell me more about this?

Also I have checked a profile on Facebook and found that the user didn't have any name to his profile? How can this be possible? Is it some database issue? Hacking or something?

When I searched over Internet, I found that `200D` is an ASCII value with an **invisible** character. Is it true?

Comment: the space character is invisible (0x20) :P

Comment: Also , you can Create nameless folder in Windows XP ,may be like that he named hisProfile. 

 press and hold the Alt key and while holding the Alt key, type numbers 0160 from the numpad. Here it is important to note that number 0160 should be typed from numpad and not from number keys present above character keys.
 Press Enter and the nameless file or folder will be created.

Comment: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3164

Comment: I have never seen any.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

How a character is represented is up to the renderer, but the server may also strip out certain characters before sending the document.

You can also have untitled YouTube videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmBvw8uPbrA by using the Unicode character [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm), or `&zwnj;` in HTML. The code block below should contain that character:

```
‌‌
```

Answer (score 150):

I just went through the character map to get these.
They are all in Calibri.

```
Number    Name                   HTML Code    Appearance
------    --------------------   ---------    ----------
U+2000    En Quad                &#8192;      " "
U+2001    Em Quad                &#8193;      " "
U+2002    En Space               &#8194;      " "
U+2003    Em Space               &#8195;      " "
U+2004    Three-Per-Em Space     &#8196;      " "
U+2005    Four-Per-Em Space      &#8197;      " "
U+2006    Six-Per-Em Space       &#8198;      " "
U+2007    Figure Space           &#8199;      " "
U+2008    Punctuation Space      &#8200;      " "
U+2009    Thin Space             &#8201;      " "
U+200A    Hair Space             &#8202;      " "
U+200B    Zero-Width Space       &#8203;      "​"
U+200C    Zero Width Non-Joiner  &#8204;      "‌"
U+200D    Zero Width Joiner      &#8205;      "‍"
U+200E    Left-To-Right Mark     &#8206;      "‎"
U+200F    Right-To-Left Mark     &#8207;      "‏"
U+202F    Narrow No-Break Space  &#8239;      " "
```

Comment: What does Calibri have to do with this?

Comment: @guival not every `font set` has the definition for every `Unicode` symbol. [As example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128276/265870)

Comment: `U+2800   Braille blank pattern   &#10240;   "⠀"`

Comment: I found some additional characters that I needed to have sanitized (like Word Joiner & OGHAM Space Mark).  Here's my list (in JSON format): https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/42c3be286185aff0476d5888f0a819ff

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a truly invisible character: `U+FEFF`.
This character is called the Byte Order Mark and is related to the Unicode 8 system. It is a really confusing concept that can be explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call/689237#689237) The Byte Order Mark or `BOM` for short is an invisible character that doesn't take up any space. You can copy the character bellow between the `>` and `<`.

Here is the character:

> >  <

How to catch this character in action:

- Copy the character between the `>` and `<`,
- Write a line of text, then randomly put your caret in the line of text
- Paste the character in the line.
- Go to the beginning of the line and press and hold the right arrow key.

You will notice that when your caret gets to the place you pasted the character, it will briefly stop for around half a second. This is becuase the caret is passing over the invisible character. Even though you can't see it doesn't mean it isn't there. The caret still sees that there is a character in that area that you pasted the BOM and will pass through it. Since the BOM is invisble, the caret will look like it has paused for a brief moment. You can past the BOM multiple times in an area and redo the steps above to really show the affect. Good luck!

EDIT: Sadly, Stackoverflow doesn't like the character. Here is an example from w3.org: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/examples/phpbomtest.php

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are correct - whether a character is invisible or not depends on what font you use. This seems to be a pretty good list to me of characters that are truly invisible (not even space). It contains some chars that the other lists are missing.

```
'\u2060', // Word Joiner
'\u2061', // FUNCTION APPLICATION
'\u2062', // INVISIBLE TIMES
'\u2063', // INVISIBLE SEPARATOR
'\u2064', // INVISIBLE PLUS
'\u2066', // LEFT - TO - RIGHT ISOLATE
'\u2067', // RIGHT - TO - LEFT ISOLATE
'\u2068', // FIRST STRONG ISOLATE
'\u2069', // POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE
'\u206A', // INHIBIT SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
'\u206B', // ACTIVATE SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
'\u206C', // INHIBIT ARABIC FORM SHAPING
'\u206D', // ACTIVATE ARABIC FORM SHAPING
'\u206E', // NATIONAL DIGIT SHAPES
'\u206F', // NOMINAL DIGIT SHAPES
'\u200B', // Zero-Width Space
'\u200C', // Zero Width Non-Joiner
'\u200D', // Zero Width Joiner
'\u200E', // Left-To-Right Mark
'\u200F', // Right-To-Left Mark
'\u061C', // Arabic Letter Mark
'\uFEFF', // Byte Order Mark
'\u180E', // Mongolian Vowel Separator
'\u00AD'  // soft-hyphen
```

Comment: There is a web site named [invisible-characters.com](https://invisible-characters.com/) which has compiled a list similar to yours. There is understandably a considerable overlap, but you have a few that they don't, and vice versa. They are missing '\u2066' through '\u2069' from your list. Conversely, your list is missing quite a few of theirs, such as U+034F (COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER) and U+200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE). That said, some entries on their list are obviously not invisible (e.g. U+0020 (SPACE) and U+200A (HAIR SPACE)), so I'd treat their list with caution.

Answer (score 2):

The question about invisible characters in Unicode deserves a more thorough explanation.

### Short answer - there are lots

Here are 134 invisible characters →`­؜᠎​‌‍‎‏‪‫‬‭‮⁠⁡⁢⁣⁤⁧⁦⁨⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯`← and here is their escaped ASCII representation: `U+00AD U+061C U+180E U+200B U+200C U+200D U+200E U+200F U+202A U+202B U+202C U+202D U+202E U+2060 U+2061 U+2062 U+2063 U+2064 U+2067 U+2066 U+2068 U+2069 U+206A U+206B U+206C U+206D U+206E U+206F U+FEFF U+1D173 U+1D174 U+1D175 U+1D176 U+1D177 U+1D178 U+1D179 U+1D17A U+E0001 U+E0020 U+E0021 U+E0022 U+E0023 U+E0024 U+E0025 U+E0026 U+E0027 U+E0028 U+E0029 U+E002A U+E002B U+E002C U+E002D U+E002E U+E002F U+E0030 U+E0031 U+E0032 U+E0033 U+E0034 U+E0035 U+E0036 U+E0037 U+E0038 U+E0039 U+E003A U+E003B U+E003C U+E003D U+E003E U+E003F U+E0040 U+E0041 U+E0042 U+E0043 U+E0044 U+E0045 U+E0046 U+E0047 U+E0048 U+E0049 U+E004A U+E004B U+E004C U+E004D U+E004E U+E004F U+E0050 U+E0051 U+E0052 U+E0053 U+E0054 U+E0055 U+E0056 U+E0057 U+E0058 U+E0059 U+E005A U+E005B U+E005C U+E005D U+E005E U+E005F U+E0060 U+E0061 U+E0062 U+E0063 U+E0064 U+E0065 U+E0066 U+E0067 U+E0068 U+E0069 U+E006A U+E006B U+E006C U+E006D U+E006E U+E006F U+E0070 U+E0071 U+E0072 U+E0073 U+E0074 U+E0075 U+E0076 U+E0077 U+E0078 U+E0079 U+E007A U+E007B U+E007C U+E007D U+E007E U+E007F`

Are there more? Yes.

Are there invisible characters in the ASCII range? Depends on the font.

### Long answer - ready? set. go!

The Unicode Standard enables anyone to read and write in their own language. To do that, it lists unique [code points](https://unicode-table.com/en/) (U+hex), that are categorized into letters (D,ž,ǅ,ʶ,愛,), symbols (+∊≠,£¥₪,҂˚˟˿), marks (ם֑֟֯ ,ী,◌҉  ), separators ( , , , ,  ), emojis (,,), and much more. ASCII/Basic Latin is the very beginning of the table and more code points are added every update.

Simply listing unique numbers for characters is not enough. Characters can change their shape or change the sentence depending on the context. To support that, every code point comes with a [list of properties](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp) . These properties may define the width (AＡ), its role in the sentence (-“.), its direction (cכ), and much more.

Most invisible characters have the property [General_Category=Format](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:General_Category=Format:%5D) (other answers here included [Spaces](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:White_Space=Yes:%5D) as well). Theis characters have a supporting role to a word/sentence. Here are some examples:

- [General Punctuation Block](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BBlock=General%20Punctuation%7D) -
  Invisible characters that are an integral part of some writing systems and emojis. Common ones are [Zero width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) (U+200D), [Zero width non joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) (U+200C), [Word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) (U+2060)
- [Explicit Bidirectional Formatting](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/) characters - 12 invisible characters used to enforce different direction constraints on the sentence. Helping present text to more than 300 million speakers of right-to-left languages e.g. Hebrew or Arabic.
- [Tags](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr27/tr27-4.html#tag) - 97 invisible characters that mirror ASCII (just drop the E and you get characters in the ASCII range). These are used as emoji modifiers and digital signatures to prove who copied your text.

This all leads to talk about exploiting invisible characters for homograph attack/visual spoofing. Sometimes it's harmless like invisible names and titles but in lots of cases they are used maliciously. For example [U+202E](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1036/002/) is one invisible character that keeps doing more harm than good [for decades](https://reasonlabs.com/research/revenge-of-the-unitrix)!!

Last point, there is another way to make invisible characters using fonts. Fonts are files that store glyphs (pictures of characters), that present the characters' look. If the font does not contain a glyph for a codepoint, a substitute/replacement character is displayed (e.g. �, □). But if the font contains a transparent glyph for a codepoint, then the character is invisible, only when displayed by that font. This is the only way to have invisible characters in the ASCII range (for example can you see →``← [U+000C Form Feed](https://unicode-table.com/en/000C/)).

Hope you find this explanation helpful and may you [check strings for invisible characters](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) more often

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use **[invisible or blank name on facebook](https://techunow.com/how-to/make-blank-invisible-name-facebook/)** by using some HTML code/symbols.

**Method 1:**

Copy and paste `(ﹺ　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　ﹺ)` symbols without brackets in your first and last name field.

**Method 2:**

Click on edit name. Now copy and paste following symbol in first and last name.

```
ՙՙ ՙՙ
```

Answer (score -1):

An invisible Character is   `​`, or `U+200b`

```
​
```

Comment: It’s one of many. What exactly does this answer add to the other existing three answers?