# Remove empty characters, blank characters, invisible characters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am performing a validation in html text box which should pass only alphabets(a-z/A-Z) and few special characters like (*,& etc..). Otherwise it should show error some error.
I had written a JavaScript function which does the same.

```
function removeInvalidCharacters(selectedElement) {
    if (selectedElement && typeof selectedElement.val() !== typeof undefined && selectedElement.val() != "") {
        selectedElement.val(selectedElement.val().replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]|[\u007F-\u00A0]/g, "").replace(/\\f/g, "").replace(/%/g,""));
    }
}
```

I am filtering `selectedElement` before passing to the function `removeInvalidCharacters`.

```
$("#name").val(toASCII($("#name").val()));
var selectedElement = $("#name").val();
```

But now I am facing a scenario in which empty characters, blank characters, invisible characters and whitespace characters are bypassing my regex. I could see some invisible characters are present in my `name` field. I want to replace these characters.

In further investigation I could found that [Invisible characters - ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978720/invisible-characters-ascii)
characters mentioned in this link are the culprits. I need to have a regex to catch them and replace them.

Eg: `AAAAAAAAAAAA‎AAAAAAAAAAA` is the value in text field. Now if we check `$("#name").val().length`, it gives 24 ,even though we could see only 23 characters. I need to remove that hidden character.

Please help me with this scenario. Hope my query is clear

UPDATE:

`var result = selectedElement.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '');` fixed my problem.
Thank you all for the support.

Comment: `val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,"")` and jQuery is not part of this

Comment: I need to pass few special characters like * also. My point is to remove the invisible characters.

Comment: `val.replace(/[^A-Za-z*]/g,"")` - add the ones you want instead of the ones you do not want

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow only (a-z/A-Z) like you mention, try this:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

Comment: I need to pass few special characters like * also. My point is to remove the invisible characters.

Comment: Do you have a list of these special chars you want to allow?

Answer (score 1):

Include the chars you want to keep instead of the ones you do not want, since that list may be incomplete

Otherwise look here: [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string)

```js
const val = `AAAAAAAAAAAA‎AAAA**AAAAAAA`;
const cleaned = val.replace(/[^A-Za-z*]/g,"");
console.log(val.length,cleaned.length);
```

Comment: How is this different to my answer?

Comment: I can look at the times, your comment says 3min ago, my answer 4min ago

Comment: I'm not saying you copy-pasted it, but it's still the same answer.