# indexOf() method returns -1 when item is present in list

Tags: javascript, indexing

```js
let mobile = [
  "‭+9384849202",
  "‭+5808789645",
  "‭+0989645643",
  "‭+7864769845",
]

console.log(mobile.indexOf("+7864769845"))
```

the result of this is `-1` when the expected result is `3`

thought it was a type error at first, but now I'm not sure?

Answer (score 5):

There is a hidden [zero-width "invisible" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978720/invisible-characters-ascii) at the start of each string in the array. If you delete them, it works as expected.

```js
let mobile = [
  "+9384849202",
  "+5808789645",
  "+0989645643",
  "+7864769845",
]

console.log(mobile.indexOf("+7864769845"))
```